# How to build Android Bindings Library for Cloudinary?

Tags: android, xamarin, cloudinary

I am attempting to build an Android Bindings Library for Cloudinary, and have comes across build errors stating "no suitable method found to override".  I am on the hunt for a resolve.  Meanwhile...

While I follow this tutorial about [building Jar Reference Lib Project](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/), adding [cloudinary-core.1.9.1.jar (maven)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.cloudinary/cloudinary-android/1.9.1), the following build errors:

```
CS0234  The type or namespace name 'AbstractFileComparator' does not exist in the namespace 'Org.Apache.Commons.IO.Comparator' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\...\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\solution\project\obj\Debug\generated\src\Org.Apache.Commons.IO.Comparator.CompositeFileComparator.cs
```

The namespace 'Com.Cloudinary' already contains a definition for 'Api'
And many others like:  'some public method': no suitable method found to override

References:
[Cloudinary github repo](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_java#cloudinary).

Answer (score 1):

There are two classes in the jar that are also package names (`Api` and `Transformation`). Java is ok with it but Xamarin/C# not so much. To make it work you'll have to change the names of the classes so they don't interfere with each other.

Another issue is that there are two derived classes (`Expression` and `Condition`) that have methods with a generic return type - this too doesn't work well with Xamarin. It can be fixed by forcing them to return `Object` instead.

---

So, in practice: Two separate jar-binding projects. One containing a single jar, the `com.cloudinary.core` one, with the build action set to `EmbeddedJar` and the `metadata.xml` looking like so:

```
<metadata>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.cloudinary']/class[@name='Api']" name="managedName">CldApi</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.cloudinary']/class[@name='Transformation']" name="managedName">CldTransformation</attr>

  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.cloudinary.transformation']/class[@name='Expression']/method[@name='newInstance']" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.cloudinary.transformation']/class[@name='Condition']/method[@name='newInstance']" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
</metadata>
```

And another project containing two jars, `cloudinary-android` with build action as `EmbeddedJar` and `com.cloudinary.core` with build action set as `ReferenceJar`.

Then you simply need to add both dll files as references in the project where you intend to use Cloudinary.